# Writing rules with one class in CSS

Tags: css

I have a question to web designers - do you think that it's fine to make CSS classes with one rule in them?
For example, I usually write classes like `.float-right`, `.center` or `margin-top-40` to apply them to divs or some other elements. But I must say that I'm not writing all CSS this way, just applying these classes in some places when it's necessary to remain flexibility, like when I have to move one link to the right or something like that.
Do you think that it's the correct way of using CSS?

Comment: i've heard about such technic of using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a base file which will include a lot of classes with one rule.
And in a different css file, you will use Sass with @extend to build your component css classes.

For example:

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.bar {
  @extend .foo;
}
```

Comment: I think it's the best way to solve this question, I won't mix css classes using this method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the examples you have mentioned, it is not necessary to write additional class for the particular style. You can write them where necessary.

Adding additional style rule adds extra class in the html markup.

You can use `@mixin` in SCSS which will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I don't really want to mix html and css. Though using @mixin sounds interesting, thank you.